# create tree comment just use one loop php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I want to create tree comments just using one loop.
I wrote this code and works well, but the problem starts where I add html tags and replace these tags in the ring.
When I do this, the variables are incorrectly displayed so they can't be checked on if.
I put here the code I wrote without HTML tags, plus the code I wrote with HTML tags and I want to replace it.
Code without using HTML tags
i want why to know. second code why not working ?
first code

```
function before($_this,$inthat){return substr($inthat,0,strpos($inthat,$_this));}
function after($_this,$inthat){if(!is_bool(strpos($inthat,$_this))){return substr($inthat,strpos($inthat,$_this)+strlen($_this));}else{return false;}}
function between($_this,$that,$inthat){return before($that,after($_this,$inthat));}
        $array_data = array(
        array("id"=>2,"parent"=>1,"parent2"=>0,"list"=>1,"type"=>1,"text"=>'test 1'),
        array("id"=>3,"parent"=>1,"parent2"=>2,"list"=>2,"type"=>2,"text"=>'test 1_1'),
        array("id"=>4,"parent"=>1,"parent2"=>3,"list"=>3,"type"=>3,"text"=>'test 1_1_1'),
        array("id"=>5,"parent"=>1,"parent2"=>0,"list"=>4,"type"=>1,"text"=>'test 2'),
        array("id"=>6,"parent"=>1,"parent2"=>5,"list"=>5,"type"=>2,"text"=>'test 2_1'),
        array("id"=>7,"parent"=>1,"parent2"=>0,"list"=>6,"type"=>1,"text"=>'test 3'),
        array("id"=>8,"parent"=>1,"parent2"=>0,"list"=>7,"type"=>1,"text"=>'test 4'),
        );
        $parent2_2 = "";
        foreach( $array_data as $val)
        {
                $parent2    = $val['parent2'];
                $text       = $val['text'];
                $type       = $val['type'];
 
                if( $parent2_2 > 0 and $parent2 == 0 and $type2 > 1 ) echo "\n".str_repeat("</div>\n",$type2);
                elseif( $parent2_2>=0 and $parent2 == 0 ) echo "\n</div>\n";
 
                echo "\n".'<div class="type_'.$type.'">'."\n";
                echo '<div>'.$text."</div>";
 
                $id2    = $val['id'];
                $parent2_2    = $val['parent2'];
                $type2       = $val['type'];
        }
        echo "\n".str_repeat("</div>\n",$type2);
```

result

```
<div class="type_1">
<div>test 1</div>
<div class="type_2">
<div>test 1_1</div>
<div class="type_3">
<div>test 1_1_1</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
 
<div class="type_1">
<div>test 2</div>
<div class="type_2">
<div>test 2_1</div>
</div>
</div>
 
<div class="type_1">
<div>test 3</div>
</div>
 
<div class="type_1">
<div>test 4</div>
</div>
```

second code with html tag

```
function before($_this,$inthat){return substr($inthat,0,strpos($inthat,$_this));}
function after($_this,$inthat){if(!is_bool(strpos($inthat,$_this))){return substr($inthat,strpos($inthat,$_this)+strlen($_this));}else{return false;}}
function between($_this,$that,$inthat){return before($that,after($_this,$inthat));}
        $array_data = array(
        array("id"=>2,"parent"=>1,"parent2"=>0,"list"=>1,"type"=>1,"text"=>'test 1'),
        array("id"=>3,"parent"=>1,"parent2"=>2,"list"=>2,"type"=>2,"text"=>'test 1_1'),
        array("id"=>4,"parent"=>1,"parent2"=>3,"list"=>3,"type"=>3,"text"=>'test 1_1_1'),
        array("id"=>5,"parent"=>1,"parent2"=>0,"list"=>4,"type"=>1,"text"=>'test 2'),
        array("id"=>6,"parent"=>1,"parent2"=>5,"list"=>5,"type"=>2,"text"=>'test 2_1'),
        array("id"=>7,"parent"=>1,"parent2"=>0,"list"=>6,"type"=>1,"text"=>'test 3'),
        array("id"=>8,"parent"=>1,"parent2"=>0,"list"=>7,"type"=>1,"text"=>'test 4'),
        );
        $insert = '<Loop><Div_Replace><div>[Text]</div></Div_Replace></Loop>';
        $insertA = "";
        $parent2_2 = "";
        $Loop = between("<Loop>", "</Loop>", $insert);
        foreach( $array_data as $val)
        {
                $insertA .= $Loop;
                $parent2    = $val['parent2'];
                $text       = $val['text'];
                $type       = $val['type'];
 
                if( $parent2_2 > 0 and $parent2 == 0 and $type2 > 1 ) $insertA = str_replace("</Div_Replace>", "\n".str_repeat("</div>\n",$type2)."\n", $insertA);
                elseif( $parent2_2>=0 and $parent2 == 0 ) $insertA = str_replace("</Div_Replace>", "\n</div>\n", $insertA);
                $insertA = str_replace("<Div_Replace>", "\n".'<div class="type_'.$type.'">'."\n", $insertA);
                $insertA = str_replace("[Text]", $text, $insertA);
 
                $id2    = $val['id'];
                $parent2_2    = $val['parent2'];
                $type2       = $val['type'];
 
        }
        $insert = str_replace("<Loop>" . $Loop . "</Loop>", $insertA, $insert);
        echo $insert;
```

result

```
<div class="type_1">
<div>test 1</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
 
<div class="type_2">
<div>test 1_1</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
 
<div class="type_3">
<div>test 1_1_1</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
 
<div class="type_1">
<div>test 2</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
 
<div class="type_2">
<div>test 2_1</div>
</div>
</div>
 
<div class="type_1">
<div>test 3</div>
</div>
</div>
 
<div class="type_1">
<div>test 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you mean of tree comments?